# Add a scroller to an inner control

Tags: wpf, scroll, wpf-controls, scrollview

I've been through similar questions here on SO but couldn't find a solution yet.
The inner control is a table:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Labster7.Application.Modules.MassiveExecution.Windows.ExperimentDetailsTableView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             MinHeight="150"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" 
             xmlns:igDP="http://infragistics.com/DataPresenter"
             xmlns:fw="clr-namespace:Labster7.Application.Framework;assembly=Labster7.Application.Framework"
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:igEditors="http://infragistics.com/Editors">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="..\Resources\Styles.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <Style TargetType="ScrollViewer" BasedOn="{StaticResource CoolScrollViewerStyle}">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </Style>
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <igDP:XamDataGrid DataSource="{Binding Path=TaskObjects, Mode=TwoWay}" MinHeight="100"
                          RecordsDeleting="DataPresenterBase_OnRecordsDeleting" 
                          RecordsDeleted="DataPresenterBase_OnRecordsDeleted" ScrollingMode="DeferredWithScrollTips">
            <igDP:XamDataGrid.Resources>
                <Style x:Key="CheckBoxedHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type igDP:LabelPresenter}">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox Name="HeaderCheckBox" Content="{Binding}" Click="OnClick" IsChecked="True" IsThreeState="False"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="igEditors:XamCheckEditor">
                    <EventSetter Event="ValueChanged" Handler="XamCheckEditorValueChanged"/>
                </Style>
            </igDP:XamDataGrid.Resources>
            <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
                <igDP:FieldLayout>
                    <igDP:FieldLayout.Fields>
                        <igDP:Field Name="IsSelected" Label="Selected" IsSelected="{Binding AllSelected}">
                            <igDP:Field.Settings>
                                <igDP:FieldSettings AllowEdit="{Binding IsEditable}" 
                                                    EditAsType="{x:Type sys:Boolean}" 
                                                    EditorType="{x:Type igEditors:XamCheckEditor}" 
                                                    LabelPresenterStyle="{StaticResource CheckBoxedHeaderStyle}" />
                            </igDP:Field.Settings>
                        </igDP:Field>
                        <igDP:Field Name="ExperimentName" Label="Experiment Name">
                            <igDP:Field.Settings>
                                <igDP:FieldSettings AllowEdit="False" />
                            </igDP:Field.Settings>
                        </igDP:Field>
                        <igDP:Field Name="Machines" Label="Machines">
                            <igDP:Field.Settings>
                                <igDP:FieldSettings AllowEdit="False" />
                            </igDP:Field.Settings>
                        </igDP:Field>
                        <igDP:Field Name="Status" Label="Status">
                            <igDP:Field.Settings>
                                <igDP:FieldSettings AllowEdit="False" />
                            </igDP:Field.Settings>
                        </igDP:Field>
                        <igDP:Field Name="StartTime" Label="Start Time"
                                    Converter="{fw:DateTimeToStringConverter FormatString=0:hh:mm:ss}">
                            <igDP:Field.Settings>
                                <igDP:FieldSettings AllowEdit="False" EditAsType="{x:Type sys:String}"/>
                            </igDP:Field.Settings>
                        </igDP:Field>
                        <igDP:Field Name="EndTime" Label="End Time"
                                    Converter="{fw:DateTimeToStringConverter FormatString=0:hh:mm:ss}">
                            <igDP:Field.Settings>
                                <igDP:FieldSettings AllowEdit="False" EditAsType="{x:Type sys:String}"/>
                            </igDP:Field.Settings>
                        </igDP:Field>
                    </igDP:FieldLayout.Fields>
                </igDP:FieldLayout>
            </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
            <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
                <igDP:FieldLayoutSettings SelectionTypeRecord="Single"/>
            </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
        </igDP:XamDataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

(`CoolScroller` is a style already used successfully in the app. It's quite long so I don't add the code for now.)

The containing window is:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Labster7.Application.Modules.MassiveExecution.Windows.ActivityEditorView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:fw="clr-namespace:Labster7.Application.Framework;assembly=Labster7.Application.Framework"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:windows="clr-namespace:Labster7.Application.Modules.MassiveExecution.Windows" mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="550"
             xmlns:igCa="http://infragistics.com/Chart">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="2"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,10,10,10" Foreground="Red"  IsReadOnly="True"
                     Visibility="{Binding ShouldShowExperimentTable,Converter={fw:BoolToVisibilityConverter TrueValue=Hidden, FalseValue=Visible}}">
                Click 'Add test from DOE' to view the activity's experiments
            </TextBox>
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Visibility="{Binding Path=ShouldShowExperimentTable, Converter={fw:BoolToVisibilityConverter TrueValue=Visible, FalseValue=Hidden}}">
                <!--<StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right" Orientation="Horizontal" MaxHeight="30" Margin="4">
                    <Label Content="Select all"/>
                    <igEditors:XamCheckEditor IsChecked="{Binding ExperimentDetailsTableViewModel.SelectAll}" IsThreeState="False" />
                </StackPanel>-->
                <windows:ExperimentDetailsTableView DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                                                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                                    Margin="3,3,3,3" 
                                                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                    DataContext="{Binding Path=ExperimentDetailsTableViewModel}" />
            </DockPanel>
        </StackPanel>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Background="SkyBlue" Height="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="Auto">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                <!--<Label MinHeight="30" MinWidth="100" Content="{Binding Stopwatch.TimeElapsed}"/>-->
                <!--<ProgressBar MinHeight="30" Maximum="100" Minimum="0" 
                             Value="{Binding Progress, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                             Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Value, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource conv}}"/>-->
            </StackPanel>
            <igCa:XamChart  Grid.Row="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowExperimentsStatusData, 
                            Converter={fw:BoolToVisibilityConverter TrueValue=Visible, FalseValue=Hidden}}"
                            MaxHeight="300" Width="Auto" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">

            </igCa:XamChart>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

(I removed the chart series as it's irrelevant binding.)
`windows:ExperimentDetailsTableView` is the inner control. I want a scroller (preferred with the style but I'm flexible) that will appear when I make the area for the table too small for it or when the table has too many rows to show in its current area. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, after removing the chart, the scroller suddenly did work. I suppose it's the same as 'restart VS'.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use a `ScrollViewer`?

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <%-- your content --%>
```